# How to convert numbers to binary and hex (without built-in functions)?

Tags: java

Since this is homework, I can't use built-in functions. I have to use algorithms in Java.

This is what I have so far but it is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangingFigures {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 0 and 127:");

        int num = scanner.nextInt ();

        String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(num); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to work fine for me, what problem are you running into?

Comment: I can't use built in functions.

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm is trivial:

```
make an empty string
do:
    prepend "n" modulo "base" to that string
    divide "n" by "base"
until (n == 0)
```

if "base" is greater than 10 you'll need to do a little work to convert the "digits" into the letters that represent 10+

Comment: +1 for providing pseudocode instead of just giving the answer (as well as the algo being right, of course). Very nicely done.

Comment: While it doesn't matter since user808520 seems to be using Java, the `div` function in the C standard library would actually be pretty nice for this sort of thing, as it allows you to calculate the modulo value in the same step as the division.

Comment: @JAB yes, if performance were an issue then calculating the division and remainder at the same time would be optimal.

Comment: Well, there's that, but I was speaking more generally. It's not just the performance but the way the code looks. On the other hand the usage of `div` could potentially be confusing to those who don't know the standard library that well, so it's still a tradeoff despite the advantages.

Answer (score -1):

To HEX:

```
String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
System.out.println(HEXES.charAt((num & 0xF0) >> 4) + "" + HEXES.charAt((num & 0x0F)));
```

[To binary](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet514.htm)

Comment: your magic-looking answer seems to be missing something, and doesn't get at the algorithm, or explain anything.  if num is 256 it fails greatly.